# Como contar totales de dos columnas distitas luego de de agrupar

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hola estoy haciendo una consulta en MYSQL pero estoy teniendo un problema de como sacar un total luego de que se agrupan los resultados, mi consulta es la siguiente :

```
SELECT 
     fi.idfacturacionprofesionalitems,
     fi.precio,
     fd.valorboleta, 
     os.periodo,
     osp.nombre, 
     fd.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada, 
     fg.idfacturacionprofesionalglobal,      
     en.matricula,
     concat(en.apellido,' ',en.nombre) as profesional,     
     en.razonsocial,
     count(fd.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada)     
  FROM 
     facturacionprofesionalitems AS fi
    LEFT JOIN facturacionprofesionaldetallada AS fd
     ON fi.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada=fd.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada
    LEFT JOIN facturacionprofesionalglobal AS fg
     ON fd.idfacturacionprofesionalglobal=fg.idfacturacionprofesionalglobal
    LEFT JOIN ctacteosplan AS os 
     ON fg.idctacteosplan=os.idctacteosplan 
    LEFT JOIN osplan AS osp
     ON os.idosplan=osp.idosplan  
    LEFT JOIN domicilio AS dom
     ON fg.iddomicilio=dom.iddomicilio 
    LEFT JOIN entidad AS en
     ON dom.identidad=en.identidad
WHERE osp.codplan=374 AND os.periodo='05/2019'
      group by fd.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada
```

con lo que obtengo como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero logar es que agrupe con un total a estos registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que me cuente un total por matricula y nose realmente como realizarlo por favor si alguien me puede dar una mano se va a agradecer

Comment: Necesitas que te agruoe por la cantidad de matriculas y que te devuelva el total por cada una de ellas, no?

Comment: Exacto Alejo, a esto que ya tiene una agrupación necesito que a su ves agrupe por matricula y devuelva el total por matricula. Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes modificar tu consulta mysql para que agrupe por matricula y te cuente cada una de esta agrupación, te quedaría algo como

```
SELECT 
     fi.idfacturacionprofesionalitems,
     fi.precio,
     fd.valorboleta, 
     os.periodo,
     osp.nombre, 
     en.matricula,
     count(en.matricula) as 'cantidad de maticulas',
     concat(en.apellido,' ',en.nombre) as profesional,     
     en.razonsocial,
     count(fd.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada)     
  FROM 
     facturacionprofesionalitems AS fi
    LEFT JOIN facturacionprofesionaldetallada AS fd
     ON fi.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada=fd.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada
    LEFT JOIN facturacionprofesionalglobal AS fg
     ON fd.idfacturacionprofesionalglobal=fg.idfacturacionprofesionalglobal
    LEFT JOIN ctacteosplan AS os 
     ON fg.idctacteosplan=os.idctacteosplan 
    LEFT JOIN osplan AS osp
     ON os.idosplan=osp.idosplan  
    LEFT JOIN domicilio AS dom
     ON fg.iddomicilio=dom.iddomicilio 
    LEFT JOIN entidad AS en
     ON dom.identidad=en.identidad
WHERE
        osp.codplan=374
    AND
        os.periodo='05/2019'
  group by
        fd.idfacturacionprofesionaldetallada, en.matricula
```

El lado malo de esto es que solo te mostraría los datos en común que tenga las filas, ejemplo, si en una fila el nombre cambia, la consulta se vería afectada, la forma mas fácil seria que hagas la consulta de agrupación aparte o anidada dentro de un select, revisa un poco sobre esto

https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043845/a-select-query-selecting-a-select-statement

Suerte y no dudes en preguntar de nuevo si tienes alguna duda

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Alejo ejecute la query pero me genera los mismos resultados que antes. cantidad de matriculas los totales son iguales a lo que agrupe previamente. Se te ocurre algo mas que pueda llegar a hacer=?

Comment: intenta hacer esto, solo agrupa la matriculas pero sin el id de facturación profesional detallada, he ignora los demas campos que solo tengas el contador de matriculas en el select, me cuentas como te va o si logras resolver, pro fa publicalo

Comment: Alejo mil gracias! modifique de raiz mi consulta y pude solucionar el problema. Gracias por la Mano !

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer en envolver esa consulta que ya tienes dentro de otra:

`select campo1, campo2,count(campo3) from (/*la consulta que ya tienes*/) group by campo1,campo2`